# How did Plava Laguna intend to deliver the stones to Leeloo?

Tags: the-fifth-element

In The Fifth Element, Leeloo was to meet with the diva Plava Laguna on Fhloston Paradise and retrieve the stones.

The Diva had promised to deliver the stones to Leeloo after the concert, but was tragically killed in the attack by the Mangalores. Corbin was forced to retrieve the stones literally from within the diva.

This begs the question: how did she *intend* to get them out of herself?

Comment: Follow-up question: How did she get them in there?

Comment: No canon backup, but, given that she is clearly non-human, I was guessing a marsupial type pouch or something.  Corbin did things the messy way.

Comment: Didn't any of you ever get taught how to smuggle heroin in bags across the border?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Diva Plavalaguna<sup>[1]</sup> **did not mean to survive the experience**.

Here's the exerpt from the [script](http://scifiscripts.com/scripts/5thelement.txt), in the scene where Diva arrives, walks past Leeloo and touches her:

> ... The Diva reaches out and strokes Leeloo's face, without touching her. The Diva removes her hand making a sound of crackling electricity, then passes on. Leeloo is groggy.
>
> The Diva's ASSISTANT comes up to her.
>
> **DIVA'S ASSISTANT:**
>   Please forgive this little incident. She wants you to know that she senses great powers in
>   you... in the service of a noble cause...
>   She will give you what you have come to get, but she wants to sing first... 
>   **One last time...**

That last details implies that Diva does not expect to survive. Whether it is because she intends to die during extraction as there's no other choice; OR because she's prescient and knows what will happen is not clear; but a latter detail from a script hints at the latter option:

---

> She [Diva] falls from the stage into Korben's arms. He lowers her to the floor.
>   Korben ignores the panic all around and wraps her in his dinner jacket,
>   trying to stop the blue blood spurting from her wounds.
>
> **KORBEN:**
>   (to the Diva)
>   I was sent by the government to help you.
>
> **DIVA:**
>   Don't worry.  **This is my fate...**
>   How was the concert?

---

<sub>[1] Presumably, the name - which means "[blue lagoon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plava_Laguna)" in Croatian - is a reference to Milla Jovovich's first film "Return to the Blue Lagoon").</sub>

Comment: Excellent! I'm surprised this ended up being cut from the script in the final version.

Comment: @phantom42 - reading the script, plenty of things were cut that I would have voted to be kept.

Comment: Nice footnote too, I love details like that!  Thought it would have been better if it were Ukrainian (given Milla's native land).  Also, according to IMDB it wasn't her *first* film, though possibly the first in which she was a lead.